# Create FTP connection using IP address on command prompt?

Tags: command-line

can we create FTP connection using command prompt with the help of IP address???

Answer (score 3):

You've not told us your operating system, but on Windows you can use the bundled command-line utility `ftp` to do this. Documentation is [here](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm).

On most Unix-based OSes, there is also a utility called `ftp`, documentation can be found by using `man ftp` or by reading [this](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ftp.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can use ftp.exe from the command prompt (located at `C:\Windows\System32\ftp.exe`).

For example:

```
ftp ftp.gnu.org
```

and

```
ftp 140.186.70.20
```

both work.

Comment: Built in? Hardly.

Comment: Its a command line program that ships with Windows, to be exact.

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'bundled', rather than 'built in' then? ;)

Comment: I smell an antitrust lawsuit!

Answer (score 1):

Most ftp clients support interactive commands, if that's what you mean. You can load the ftp program and then choose an IP destination, authenticate, and so on:

$ **ftp**
ftp> **open 198.232.168.117**
220 (ftp.sun.com:mfe): **anonymous**
331 Guest login ok, send your complete e-mail address as password.
Password: **xxxxx**
230 Guest login ok, access restrictions apply.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>